# Error al compilar .py con pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Buenas, estoy tratando de compilar un archivo .py con pyinstaller (anteriormente probe con py2exe tambien) mediante el comando en consola: 
"pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed nombre.py" y cuando finaliza el proceso se genera el correspondiente archivo .exe, pero al abrirlo muestra el mensaje de error "failed to execute script nombre".
Si reviso el proceso que se ha realizado en la consola de símbolo del sistema puedo ver una serie de warnings como los de la imagen adjunta [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].
Por otro lado, en la carpeta build que genera el proceso de compilación tengo un archivo llamado warning.txt con los siguientes errores [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].
¿Donde esta mi error? Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Existe un bug de pyinstaller que intenta importar punteros de **C**, este se identifica como un falso positivo, ya que aunque no se importan directamente, se utiliza la api del sistema en el que el programa se ejecuta, se puede solucionar instalando el paquete de distribución de **C++** para ordenadores anteriores a windows 10, pero es un problema menor

en cuanto a tu problema de ejecución, deberás verificar/hacer lo siguiente:

- Crear una archivo **SPEC** para el programa `nombre.py`
- Verificar que las opciones seleccionadas coincidan con el archivo
  SPEC
- Verificar que modulos son escritos en python y cuales tienen enlaces
  binarios a bibliotecas en **C**
- Añadir los binarios encontrados a el archivo **SPEC** para que los
  empaquete dentro del directorio
- Verificar que todas las bibliotecas de terceros este añadidas ya sea
  al archivo **SPEC** o al archivo de ejecución principal, esto es, si
  `nombre.py` importa un archivo dentro del mismo directorio: `Nombre2.py`
  y dentro de este se importa una biblioteca que no aparezca dentro de
  `nombre.py`, esta biblioteca puede no ser importada y sea lo que te
  cause los errores

una vez compilado el programa a un directorio, verifica que todo funcione correctamente, si falla, haz arreglos manuales, enlistarlos y trata de añadirlos ya sea a el archivo **SPEC**, o a nombre.py para que la próxima vez que busques compilar tu proyecto, este se ejecute sin problemas,

un consejo, busca usar un directorio de distribución, te causara menos problemas y acelera la carga del programa, para mejorar tus tiempos de desarrollo, intenta usar el modelo de launcher, para solo compilar una vez un launcher que llame a la funcion principal de `nombre.py` y que importe las bibliotecas necesarias. asi cada vez que modifiques `nombre.py`, se notara el camio inmediatamente.

una vez tengas todo funcionando puedes decidir entre dejar el modelo de launcher o pasar todo a un archivo unico

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo saber qué módulos tienen enlaces binarios a bibliotecas de C?

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario añadir el .exe al comando, simplemente puedes escribir:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed nombre.py
```

Ya si quieres añadir una carpeta o algo más, incluso añadir un icono personalizado a tu aplicación puedes usar:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --add-data "nombre_carpeta;nombre_carpeta" -i "ruta/del/archivo/icono.ico" nombre.py
```